# Disable auto-scroll in IntelliJ Terminal

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I want to start debugging while my program is still running and producing output. The scroll position always jumps to the newest output. I want to disable this auto-scroll behaviour (and re-enable it) when necessary.

I remember other tools/terminals that stop auto-scrolling if you manually scroll in their window. Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: Do you mean the Run console or the Terminal tool window? These are completely different consoles with different behaviors. In the Run console autoscroll is disabled if you move the cursor above the last line. Autoscroll is active only when the caret is at the last line of the output.

Comment: I mean the Terminal tool window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible for the **Terminal** tool window at the moment, please check the following open requests:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140061
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136403

Comment: Seems like it will soon be fixed: Fix versions 2018.1

Answer (score 2):

```
ctrl +s will suspend the terminal process
ctrl +q will resume the terminal process
```

Not a actual solution but a work around

Comment: Very useful, saved me from re-running a very slow command

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about the `Run Console`, in which case there is a button that will disable autoscroll:

[image: the purple arrow]

The button with the purple down arrow toggles autoscroll on and off

Comment: No, it doesn't. It just scrolls to the end of the log. My view is refocused every time new log messages appear, independently if it is at the end of log or somewhere in the middle.

Comment: He meant about the Terminal window, not run console